# how do i add a text "0" from the format date which i converted to MM-DD-yyyy")

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am pulling up the date "ddMMyyyy" from a database , then convert the date into MM-dd-yyyy" before display the output. For some reason, there are  dates that contains only 7 digits which by default it must be 8 digits.

When the system find that the digits in the date is less 8 characters it throws an error converting the date, as an option I'm thingking of adding 0 in the day when it display the output. for example 08-12-1983, from database by default 8-12-1983

I want to add 0 on the day when it display the output.

I used vb.net and sql command.

Here is my code.

```
Public BGC1, BGC2, BGC3, BGC4 As String
Public str As String

 Public Sub GetBGC()
        Try
            myConnection.Open()
            'Main.PresStartResults.Text = "Prestart Checks : "
            'Main.BGCName.Text = "Employee Name "
            'Main.BGCDOB.Text = "DOB"
            'Dim str As String
            str = "SELECT * FROM tblEmp WHERE (EmpID = '" & ADS.UserEmpID & "')"
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            While dr.Read()
                Dim stringinp = dr("DOB").ToString
                Dim DateTime1 = DateTime.ParseExact(stringinp, "ddMMyyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                Dim outp = DateTime1.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
                BGC3 = outp


            End While


        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox("Unable to Connect to BGC DB. You may not have access or DB not available." & ex.ToString)
        End Try

myConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Why tag c# though?

Comment: because vb.net is close to c# and i am able to read  some  c# codes

Comment: Firstly, why are you storing dates as text instead of as dates in the database?

Comment: @Veck `Java` is close to `c#` too.

Comment: That doesn't mean that this question has anything to do with C#.  Tags are to indicate what the question relates to, not a way to get as many people as possible to read your question.  What about the C# developers who can't read VB?

Comment: Not sure about VB, but after the line `Dim stringinp = dr("DOB").ToString` why not something like `stringinp = stringinp.Length < 8 ? "0" + stringinp : stringinp`?

Comment: hi Dim  stringinp = dr("DOB")  , reads the data from the database and convert it tostring

Comment: "I'm thingking of adding 0 in the day" - How can you make the assumption that the day needs to be zero padded?  `1111995` could be **01**111995 or 11**01**1995.   Are you certain that the field is a `String` type?  What does `dr.GetFieldType(dr.GetOrdinal("dob")).ToString()` produce?

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System
Imports System.Globalization

Public Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()

        Dim dateValue as DateTime
        Dim stringinp as String
        stringinp = "8-12-1983"
        Dim formats = New String(){"dd-MM-yyyy", "d-MM-yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy"}

        For Each format as String in formats
            If DateTime.TryParseExact(stringinp, formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, dateValue)
                Exit For            
            End If
        Next

        Console.WriteLine(dateValue)

    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: You should not be posting code that doesn't compile in an answer.

Comment: hi jmcilhinney, the dates in the database was uploaded by someoneElse as Text instead of dates.unfortunately i dont have access to modify to change the data type into date/time

Comment: How's that mate?

Comment: hello andrew, this actually works, it is not throwing an error however the output is in time format not date

Comment: I have removed my down-vote but your loop is still dodgy.  `TryParseExact` allows you to pass a `String` containing one format specifier or a `String` array containing multiple.  You're doing the latter and yet you are doing it in a loop, once for each format specifier, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `PadLeft` method, like this:

```
Dim stringinp = dr("DOB").ToString().PadLeft(8, "0")
```

It will append zeros at the beginning of a string until the length of a string equals to 8.

Answer (score 0):

try This

```
str = "SELECT * FROM tblEmp WHERE (EmpID = '" & ADS.UserEmpID & "')"
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            While dr.Read()
                dim mydate as Date = dr("DOB")
                Dim outp = mydate.tostring("M/dd/yyyy")
                BGC3 = outp


            End While
```

or

```
Dim outp = mydate.tostring("MM/dd/yyyy")
```